# jQuery address: $.address.change is called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery address to update address in my web application.

```
    $.address.state(url);
    $.address.update();
```

this will update address. Also, I am tracking address change using:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {
        alert("address.changed");
        ...
         });
```

The $.address.change() function is called twice. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing `$.address.state(url);` you actually make changes to the address, when you do `$.address.update();` you also do as you update it. That's why it's called twice.

Comment: so to change address in address bar, `$.address.state(url);` only is needed?